# React-Datepicker not displaying at all

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using React and trying to add a Datepicker, but the component won't display at all—-it has height and width 0x0.

For reference, I'm using

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-datepicker": "^4.16.0",
```

installed via NPM.

I tried to test with the simplest possible example (below) and still nothing is displaying.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

export default function DateTest(props) {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());  

    return (
        <div style={{width: "20em", height: "20em"}}>
            <DatePicker
                portalId="unique-root"
                placeholderText="abc123"
                selected={startDate}
                onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add the `inline` prop?

Comment: Can't reproduce. See https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76807391-99klg9?file=/src/App.js